# Graph, RDFS Reasoner, Model, Dataset, and persistor: What order of construction?

Tags: jena

I have developed an implementation of `Dataset` over MongoDB, patterned after the SDB implementation.   A `Dataset` is a unnamed (default) `Graph` plus 0 or more optional named `Graph` and is the fundamental data carrier.  The `Graph` interface declares the vital method variations of `Iterator<Triple> find()` which are implementated concretely in my code by going after data in a MongoDB collection:

```
        JenaMongoConnection mc = new JenaMongoConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        JenaMongoStore ms = new JenaMongoStore(mc, "semantic");

        Dataset ds = JenaMongoDataset.create(ms, "semtest1");
```

Initial experiments yielded a `Dataset` that worked but I am not getting the oh-so-desirable RDFS inference logic.   This is likely because in fact, no RDFS reasoner (or use of `ModelFactory.createOntologyModel()` seems to be present. My other experiments before the MongoDB integration used `ModelFactory.createOntologyModel()` and I programmatically added material to the model, then called `DatasetFactory.create(model)` to yield the `Dataset` that can be passed to the ARQ query engine.  Not surprisingly, the RDFS `subClassOf` machinery is properly invoked:

```
        mm = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        add(mm, "A", "Item");
        add(mm, "B", "A");
        add(mm, "C", "B");
        Dataset ds = DatasetFactory.create(mm); // same interface as above
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, ds) ;
        ResultSet rs = qe.execSelect() ;
```

So the question becomes:  How does one efficiently set up a `Dataset` provider with a custom `Graph` implementation that can use the RDFS reasoner?  At the moment, I am "cheating" a bit by getting the (default?) model from the `Graph` and rewrapping it with the RDFS reasoner and building the dataset from that:

```
    Graph g = new JenaMongoGraph(various args);
    Model model = ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(g);
Model rdfsModel = ModelFactory.createRDFSModel(model);

    Dataset ds = DatasetFactory.create(rdfsModel); 
    // proceed "as normal" from here
```

In short, I am getting the `Dataset` from the model, not simply from the `Graph` which is what SDB was doing.  This works -- but is there a better way?   There is a tension between `Graph`"running the show" with respect to `find()` and `Model` carrying the reasoning information.